# How to use user's input on a prompt to search something up on wiki

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make it so the user input is searched on wiki or whatever site.

```
var input = prompt();

if(input === "") {
    window.location.href = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs");
};
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Store the user input in a variable
var input = prompt();

// If the input wasn't empty, continue
if (input !== "") {

    // Send the user to the URL concatenating the input onto the end
    window.location.href = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take the user's input and swap out any spaces with underscores, then slap it on the end of the query:

```
var input = prompt();

// Replace any spaces with underscores and remove any trailing spaces
input = input.trim().split(' ').join('_');

// If the user gave some input, let's search
if(input.length) {
    window.location.href = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + input);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you wanted to search Wikipedia, you could append your search term as a querystring parameter to Wikipedia's search URL as seen below :

```
// Prompt the user for something to search Wikipedia for
var input = prompt();
// If you actually have something, then search for it
if(input.trim().length > 0){
    // Replace any spaces with + characters and search
    window.location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=' + input.replace(' ','+');
}
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
var input = prompt('What do you want to search Wikipedia for?');
if(input.trim().length > 0){
    /// Replace any spaces with + characters and search
    window.location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=' + input.replace(' ','+');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To search a Wiki or another site, you need to be familiar with the URL structure of the site. For instance, you can launch searches on Wikipedia by using the format "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=user+input"

Using a similar code to Nick Zuber, you can accomplish this.

```js
var input = prompt();

// Replace any spaces with pluses
input = input.split(' ').join('+');

// If the user gave some input, let's search
if(input.length) {
    window.location.href = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=" + input);
};
```